Solving two quadratic inequalities with two variables
Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be fixed positive numbers. Suppose that both inequalities
$$
A - \frac{1}{x} - 2xB > 0,
$$
$$
C - \frac{1}{x} - 2xD > 0,
$$
have solution for $x>0$. I want to find a region $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+$ (as large as possible, at least not a subset of $\{x=y\}$) such that
$$
A - \frac{1}{x} - (x + y)B > 0,
$$
$$
C - \frac{1}{y} - (x + y)D > 0,
$$
for $(x,y) \in U$. Solving the first equation, we have
$$
x \in \left( \frac{-(y B - A) - \sqrt{(y B - A)^2 - 4B}}{2B}, \frac{-(y B - A) + \sqrt{(y B - A)^2 - 4B}}{2B} \right).
$$
Solving the second equation, we have
$$
y \in \left( \frac{-(x D - C) - \sqrt{(x D - C)^2 - 4D}}{2D}, \frac{-(x D - C) + \sqrt{(x D - C)^2 - 4D}}{2D} \right).
$$
I do not know how to proceed next.

I have edited my question. I think $x,y$ should be positive.

It's certainily possible for either inequality to have no solutions, for example if $B=1$ and $A<2$.

@AnneBauval Let's assume that both $A-1/x-2xB>0$ and $C-1/x-2xD>0$ have solutions, let's say $x_0$. Then $x=y=x_0$ will be one of the solutions to my problem. If the vertices of the parabolas $f_1(x)=A-1/x-2xB>0$ and $f_2(x)=C-1/x-2xD$ are far enough away from the horizon axis, I think there is a small open set containing $x=y=x_0$ such that the inequalities hold within this small open set, with some $x\neq y$.
